# Ruby's double colon (::) operator usage differences

Tags: ruby

Is there any difference between

```
module Foo
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

and

```
module Foo
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Constants in Ruby are nested like files and directories in filesystem. So, constants are uniquely identified by their paths.

To draw an analogy with the file system:

```
::Rails::Engine #is an absolute path to the constant.
# like /Rails/Engine in FS.

Rails::Engine #is a path relative to the current tree level.
# like ./Rails/Engine in FS.
```

Here is the illustration of possible error:

```
module Foo

  # We may not know about this in real big apps
  module Rails
    class Engine 
    end
  end

  class Engine1 < Rails::Engine
  end

  class Engine2 < ::Rails::Engine
  end
end

Foo::Engine1.superclass
 => Foo::Rails::Engine # not what we want

Foo::Engine2.superclass
 => Rails::Engine # correct
```

Comment: Right. So if you were to call Rails::Engine from a module using the name `Module Foo`, it may interpret it as `Foo::Rails::Engine`. I've seen errors like this at times and had to add the additional `::` in front of an include.

Comment: It was taken from the book "Metaprogramming Ruby" by Paolo Perrotta. Very useful book to deepen the knowledge of the Ruby.

Comment: Nice analogy. This becomes problematic when one has modules with the same name in different scopes, since Ruby seems to use the first/nearest one it can find.

Comment: A subtle point: if `Rails::Engine` is defined outside of `Foo` and it is also **not** defined inside `Foo` then `Foo::Engine1.superclass` will be `Rails::Engine` as desired.

Answer (score 5):

```
Rails::Engine #is a path relative to the current tree level.
# like ./Rails/Engine in FS.
```

This is not quite true!

Let's have an example:

```
module M
  Y = 1
  class M
    Y = 2
    class M
      Y = 3
    end
    class C
      Y = 4
      puts M::Y
    end
  end
end

# => 3

module M
  Y = 1
  class M
    Y = 2
    class C
      Y = 4
      puts M::Y
    end
  end
end

# => 2

module M
  Y = 1
  class M
    Y = 2
    class M
      Y = 4
      puts M::Y
    end
  end
end

# => 4
```

So when you say M::Y ruby looks up for the closest defintion no matter if it is inside the current scope or outer scope or outer outer scope etc.

Comment: which Ruby is this? On 2.2.4 I get 3, 3, and 4 and many "top level constant already referenced warnings"