# How do I Make a Constant from a Gem Available in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a feeling this is a dumb one, but I've spent some time trying to figure it out and googling it, and to no avail. I'm trying to use a Ruby Gem in a Controller. I have included it in my Gemfile, run bundle install, seen it show up in my gems list, restarted my local server. But somehow whenever I try to call the gem ( [rails_rrdtool](https://github.com/bluescripts/rails_rrdtool) ) It just tells me

```
uninitialized constant RrdgraphsController::RRD
app/controllers/rrdgraphs_controller.rb:22:in `show'
```

The spot in my code where it wigs is when I'm calling

```
RRD.graph
```

It's as though it doesn't know where the heck the gem is... However, I can use require to import it successfully into an irb session. So I know that it works, it's just not getting in there some how...

Bundler should be handling the inclusion of the gem I assume. Am I calling it in the wrong place?

Comment: what gem is it? you need to prefix the constant with the right class. right now it thinks it is defined inside of the RrdgraphsController class. It's a namespace issue, I think.

Comment: Nevermind on the comment above, I didn't realize that it was the gem name as well. I thought it was just a constant defined inside of the gem. What about prefixing it with :: to try to get it to look outside the current class? `::RRD.graph`

Comment: @jstim Whoo hoo! That appears to have done it :) I was wondering if it needed some kind of prefix, but didn't think it would work with just :: If you submit it as an answer I'll give you a stamp of approval! Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if Ruby got confused because the class name is all upper case. If it was a class called `Rrd` I wonder if it would still freak out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a namespacing issue. Your error says it is looking for the constant inside of the current class: `RrdgraphsController::RRD` when it should be looking for a class outside of the current context.

Try prefixing the class name with a double colon to fully define the location of the class.

```
::RRD.graph #rest of your code
```

There's a good analogy of what this does in [this other accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482772/rubys-double-colon-operator-usage-differences). Basically it creates an absolute path so Ruby doesn't have to guess.