# What is the different between ::Rails::Engine and Rails::Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby’s double colon (::) operator usage differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482772/rubys-double-colon-operator-usage-differences)

I've made a [font-awesome plugin](https://github.com/goofansu/rails-font-awesome) for Rails, in `lib/rails-font-awesome.rb`

```
module Rails
  module Font
    module Awesome
      class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Can I use Rails::Engine instead?

Comment: @atmaish Sorry for my not searching enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`::` before `Rails` tells this to skip the normal traversing up the hierarchy to find the class and just go straight to the top.